# How to switch to the buffer where the file with a given name is opened in Vim?

Tags: vim

Is there a function in Vim which will switch to a buffer? For example, if I know that I have the `TODO.txt` file open in some window in some tab, I’d like to jump to that tab and focus that window. Is that possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`set swb=useopen,usetabe` will set make `:sb [number]` or `:sb [pattern]` switch to an open window in whichever tab.

Comment: Hrm… Either things have changed in 7.3 (I'm on 7.2), or `swb` doesn't quite do what I want. In 7.2, it seems like `swb` is only checked when jumping to errors and using quickfix and stuff. When I've got `set swf=useopen,usetab`, running `:b foo` still replaces the current window with the buffer matching `foo`.

Comment: @David Wolever, your absolutely correct. You should be using `:sb` instead of `:b`. I have corrected the post.

Answer (score 3):

I believe it's `:drop filename`

Comment: Hhmm… Close, although that requires the full path to the file, which kind of sucks if you've got a bunch of files open (where as, with buffers, you can tab-complete fairly easily).

Answer (score 0):

I use

```
 :buf TODO
```

you need a unique identifiying piece of the buffers filename. You can use tab-completion, though :)

Oh IC, just noted that you want to activate the corresponding tab. Sry